# C# Entityframework - How to convert navigation property from HashSet to SortedSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, hashset, sortedset

I'm creating my models using ADO.NET (from mysql db).
I have 3 tables : shoppinglist, item and a shoppinglist_item table (that has two FK one for shoppinglist id and the other one for item id) so each shopping list contains a list of items - and each item can be related to several shopping lists.

My problem is that the entityframework creates the shopping list object with items objects in HashSet but I need it to be a SortedSet.
I haven't found where I can change it, if I change it from the .cs then I get the following exception:

```
Additional information: Unable to set field/property items on entity type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.shopping_list_EAE115FEC280D7AC938BAF17234485EE2BD5991A4D35FE9206D03456BE962D8D. See InnerException for details.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Models.shopping_list>' to 'Models.shopping_list'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a field in shoppinglist table which contains the ordering of the items ids in the list (for example : 1,20,3) and on the code where I need to get the items by their order :

```
foreach (string itemId in shopping_list.itemsOrder.Split(',')) {
    item item = shopping_list.items.Where(i => i.id.ToString() == itemId).First(); 
    .....
}
```